# Loading curvedText via JSON no longer works in fabricJS 1.7.3

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using the excellent plugin for fabricjs, "curvedText" from https://github.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText

This works great, however, a recent update to fabricjs has rendered the plugin to stop loading via JSON. The following snippets demonstrate this.

Both the following snippets are exactly the same apart from the version of fabricJS being used.

1.7.2 version:

```js
$(function () 
{
  canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var CurvedText = new fabric.CurvedText('CurvedText',
    {
        left: 100,top: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fill: '#0000FF',radius: 150,
        fontSize: 20,spacing: 20
    });
    canvas.add(CurvedText).renderAll();

  $('#save').click(function() {
   var design = JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON());
    canvas.clear();
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.loadFromJSON(design, function() {
      console.log('loaded');      
      canvas.renderAll();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.2/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText/master/fabric.curvedText.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="160"></canvas><br/>
<button id="save">Save/Reload</button>
```

1.7.3 version:

```js
$(function () 
{
  canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    var CurvedText = new fabric.CurvedText('CurvedText',
    {
        left: 100,top: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fill: '#0000FF',radius: 150,
        fontSize: 20,spacing: 20
    });
    canvas.add(CurvedText).renderAll();

  $('#save').click(function() {
   var design = JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON());
    canvas.clear();
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.loadFromJSON(design, function() {
      console.log('loaded');      
      canvas.renderAll();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.3/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/EffEPi/fabric.curvedText/master/fabric.curvedText.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="160"></canvas><br/>
<button id="save">Save/Reload</button>
```

The 1.7.2. version works fine, the 1.7.3. version does not. The saving process seems fine, but when loading the JSON nothing seems to happen.

Looking at the release notes of 1.7.3 ( https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/releases/tag/v1.7.3 ) it seems that a change to :

"Improvement: Better error managment in loadFromJSON #3586"

...may be responsible. Any ideas?

**Additional**

There are no console errors and no network errors. As stated the scripts are identical except the version of fabric being used. The JSON I am talking about is generated from fabric itself. This allows designs to be saved and loaded. Clicking the save/reload button generates the JSON which is then reloaded (as a test). The loading mechanism breaks when loading `JSON` containing `curvedText` items. No messages are presented in any way.

Comment: Any erros in console ? Any deprecation warnings in 1.7.2 ? Also not to be pedantic but could you outline the problem a little more clear ? When you say stopped loading JSON.. What you mean ? Network tab in a chrome window failing ?\ AND Are the two code samples you entered the same ? If so, remove one because comparing takes time.. I notice no differences.. EDIT : Both 'code runs' work the same..

Comment: @Pogrindis See edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, finally tracked down the bug in `fabric.curvedText.js`. Well, the code in `fabricjs`'s `enlivenObjects` function has changed from 1.7.2. to 1.7.3. causing curvedText objects to stop loading.

If one changes the `fromObject` code in fabric.CurvedText from:

```
fabric.CurvedText.fromObject=function (object)
{
    return new fabric.CurvedText(object.text, clone(object));
};
```

to this:

```
fabric.CurvedText.fromObject=function (object, callback)
{
    var newObject = new fabric.CurvedText(object.text, clone(object));
    if(typeof callback !== "undefined")
        callback(newObject, false);
    else
        return(newObject);
};
```

Then loading will now work. Hope this helps someone else!